# How to install SSL when using Google Domains and a Google Bucket for static hosting?

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up HTTPS so that I can use HTML5 geo-location for a location map web app. I'm using Google Domains and have it linking to a Google storage bucket for static hosting. I'm wondering how I get an SSL certificate set up using Google Domains?

I would like to note [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl) has been of no help since it assumes you're linking it to an app running on Google App Engine and there is no app to link to, it's just a domain and a hosting bucket.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to serve static Cloud Storage content over HTTPS using only the Google Cloud Platform.  As per the [static hosting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#https) linked by Nadir in another answer:

> SSL is not currently supported by the Cloud Storage webservers; thus, you can only use a CNAME redirect with HTTP.

The recommended way of serving GCS content over HTTPS at this time is to use a third-party CDN.

If you would like the ability to serve static content from GCS over HTTPS directly without a third-party, I recommend filing a feature request on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).  If doing so, please link to this newly filed feature request in a comment below so that others in the community can follow along.

Comment: While you are free to choose any cloud provider you like, I'd recommend filing a feature request for this one if you'd like to stick with Cloud Storage.  We regularly monitor our issue tracker and forward such useful ideas to the appropriate engineering teams.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can purchase the SSL certificate from a SSL service provider like Comodo SSL or Rapid SSL. You will then have to install the SSL certificate on your web server.

If you are using Google Buckets for static website hosting, then you should read this link: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#https